# Best Possible String replacement In Memory

Tags: c#, string, memory, optimization

I need to replace a huge string say ~3MB in size. The replacement has to be done in-memory. I know the start and the end tag but not their indices (obviously) The replacement string is almost of the equal or lesser size!
For example:
`< hello >
jaskhdjksehrf87897g8df7g8d7g8dfy9g6d89sg78dfgy9df69g87s97090dgs8d7f6srsd564f5sd45f46sd5f76d5g68df6g785sd67g58576sd5g875sdfg578df6g6sd87g6f89g69s6d8g6 AND MUCH MORE < /hello >`

The replacement string would have another start and end tag which has to be replaced with the existing one.
Can someone help me out with the best possible method with the least time complexity in doing it. I need to do it in C#.

P.S. Remember the string is not in a file!

Comment: [KMP is your friend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43160027/335858)

Comment: Since, I know the start and the end tag and am not bothered about the existing string at all! Dont you think there is a better way to do it?
KMP would read the whole string! I wanna avoid that!

Comment: 3MB isn't all that big, unless you're doing this a lot, does it really matter how it's done?

Comment: Your string is in-memory so you have already read it. Your whole performance issue is likely to be tiny compared to the I/O for getting it.

Comment: I have like ~1400 such 3 MB strings!

Comment: When this is about XML (HTML ?) then doing it reliably might be the bigger challenge. Are the tags unique?

Comment: Yes, the tags are unique!

Comment: So you have ~1400 3MB strings in memory?

Comment: Not all in-memory yet! about ~570 are in memory already! But many more would soon be populated

Comment: It's not really clear why you're so concerned about performance and optimisation here. You have 1400 strings which will all ultimately be in memory so just process them there using any method that works. Also, this seems relevant... https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: What was the goal again? Given a string and two tags, replace them with another two tags? You can at least provide the desired method signature.

Comment: Given a string and two tags, replace them with another two tags and a replacement string between them!

Comment: Just for clarity, I guess you know that the `string` is immutable, so the method should create and return a new string?

Comment: So basically you want to replace the text between the hello tags (or any named tag) with something different?  Is this XML (and structured) or HTML?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, it must create and return a new one - That's obvious!

Comment: @JonClarke Structured XML

Comment: Just use `StringBuilder`, try it out and if it's too slow *for your purposes* then look to optimising it. Right now, there's no way to even tell what sort of performance would be acceptable, only you can test and figure that out.

Comment: To clarify your question, you have "<hello>blah blah</hello>", and this needs to be replaced with some other string, so the output should be: "<hello>xyzxyz....</hello>"? Do provide a complete demo example so it is easier to understand.

Comment: <Tag1>string 1</Tag1> to be replaced by <Tag2>string 2</Tag2>

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: You appear to be modifying XML. Depending on where the XML is coming from, and where it's going to, you could get away with no big string replacement at all by leveraging `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` and switching on the element types as you stream them. As a benefit, this would allow you to process XML of practically any size regardless of available memory.

Comment: In the exceptional case where the tag to be replaced is no bigger than the tag you're replacing, this can be done without allocating a new string, albeit not without cheating. Strings in .NET are nominally immutable, but techniques exist to mutate them anyway, so you can overwrite the tag directly (padding with spaces if necessary). But due to the restriction on the length, this is only rarely useful, and due to breaking immutability, not something you'd consider in general.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best you can do in my opinion.

First you locate the start/end tag positions within the input string. I see no better way than using linear search with [`string.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The only optimization would be to search for end tag starting from the end position of the start tag.

Then you can calculate the resulting string length, allocate `char[]` buffer, copy the unchanged parts of the input string and the replacement strings into appropriate places using the [`string.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and finally create and return a string from the buffer using the corresponding `string` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Something like this (no validations):

```
static string Replace(string input, string startTag, string endTag, string newStartTag, string newEndTag, string newContent)
{
    // Determine tags start/end positions
    int startTagStart = input.IndexOf(startTag);
    if (startTagStart < 0) return input; // or throw exception
    int startTagEnd = startTagStart + startTag.Length;
    int endTagStart = input.IndexOf(endTag, startTagEnd);
    if (endTagStart < 0) return input; // or throw exception
    int endTagEnd = endTagStart + endTag.Length;

    // Determine the resulting string length and allocate a buffer
    int resultLength = startTagStart + newStartTag.Length + newContent.Length + newEndTag.Length + (input.Length - endTagEnd);
    var buffer = new char[resultLength];
    int pos = 0;

    // Copy the substring before the start tag
    input.CopyTo(0, buffer, pos, startTagStart);
    pos += startTagStart;
    // Copy the new start tag
    newStartTag.CopyTo(0, buffer, pos, newStartTag.Length);
    pos += newStartTag.Length;
    // Copy the new content
    newContent.CopyTo(0, buffer, pos, newContent.Length);
    pos += newContent.Length;
    // Copy the new end tag
    newEndTag.CopyTo(0, buffer, pos, newEndTag.Length);
    pos += newEndTag.Length;
    // Copy the substring after the end tag
    input.CopyTo(endTagEnd, buffer, pos, input.Length - endTagEnd);

    // Create and return a string from the buffer
    return new string(buffer);
}
```

Test using the example from your comments:

```
var input = "<Tag1>string 1</Tag1>";
var output = Replace(input, "<Tag1>", "</Tag1", "<Tag2>", "</Tag2>", "string 2");
// output == "<Tag2>string 2</Tag2>"
```